# How to interface a java application with a local database in Mac os x

Tags: java, mysql, macos, jdbc

I'm trying to keep the JDBC Driver, but i don't see the mac os x version. In mySql Site there is only for  Windows or independent platform.

Can someone explain me how I can use my java application with my mysql database? 
What should I do?

Comment: you can find guide to install Mysql connectors on mac @ http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-mac-edition/w/wiki/10916.mysql-getting-and-setting-jdbc-driver.aspx

Comment: The MySQL JDBC driver is platform independent; the difference between windows and 'independent platform' is just that the first is a MSI that 'unzips' itself into a folder and the second a basic zip or tar.gz that you need to extract yourself; the content is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download MySQL JDBC driver:

1. Go to MySQL Connector/J download page @ http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
2. In the Select Platform combobox choose Platform Independent

then follow this http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-mac-edition/w/wiki/10916.mysql-getting-and-setting-jdbc-driver.aspx article to install on Mac.